# Does the cone of copositive matrices include the cone of positive semidefinite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, copositivity

I'm trying to prove that the cone of copositive matrices is closed and in Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) it says that:

> $K$ has nonempty interior, because **it includes the cone of positive semidefinite matrices**, which has nonempty interior.

I can't make sense of this. Since the definition of a copositive matrix is

$$ x^T A x \geq 0,\quad \forall x \geq 0 $$

but for a positive semidefinite matrix all $x$ would be considered. It seems to me that positive semidefnite matrices are a more "general" concept and a less strict constraint than copositivity.

Am I misunderstanding the relationship between cones and sets?

Comment: It is "easier" to be copositive than to be p.s.d. -- you have to satisfy the condition $x^TAx\ge0$ for fewer vectors. So any p.s.d. matrix is copositive, but a copositive matrix may not be p.s.d. (e.g. $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$). It's an easy mistake to make, I was confused for a minute there too.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you! The constraint on $x$ is something different from $x^TAx \geq 0$. Positive semidefiniteness must be satisfied for more vectors compared to what is required for copositivity! Will you supply an answer, then I'll accept it!

Comment: Which chapter of the book?

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $$C_1=\{A: A\text{ is a real symmetric } n \times n \text{ matrix and } X'AX \ge 0 \text{ for all $n$ vector } X \ge 0\}$$

and

$$C_2=\{A: A\text{ is a real symmetric } n \times n \text{ matrix and } X'AX \ge 0 \text{ for all $n$ vector } X\}$$

Obviously, if $A$ belongs to $C_2$, then $A$ belongs to $C_1$. Anyway, I think you are involved with this proposition: "more constraints cause smaller feasible space". Ok, we can see the proof from this angle:

2. For a copositive matrix $A$, the quadratic term $X'AX$ must be nonnegative only for those vectors $X$ satisfy the constraint $X \ge 0$, while for positive semidefiniteness the quadratic form must be satisfied the constraints $X \ge 0$, $X \le 0$ and all of vectors $X$ which are neither nonnegative nor nonpositive. In other words, for positive semidefiniteness we need more constraints to be satisfied.